# AUC in Weka vs R

Tags: r, weka, auc

I have received AUCs and prediction from a collaborated generated in Weka. The statistical model behin that was cross validated, so my dataset with the predictions includes columns for fold, predicted probability and true class. Using this data I was unable to replicate the AUCs given the predicted probabilities in R. The values always differ slightly.

Additional details:

- Weka was used via GUI, not command line
- I checked the AUC in R with packages pROC and ROCR
- I first tried calculating the AUC over the collected predictions (without regard to fold) and I got different AUCs
- Then I tried calculating the AUCs per fold and averaging. This did also not match.
- The model was ridge logistic regression and there is a single tie in the predictions
- The first fold has one sample more than the others. I have tried taking a weighted average, but this did not work out either
- I have even tested averaging the AUCs after logit-transformation (for normality)
- Taking the median instead of the mean did not help either

I am familiar with how the AUC is calculated in R, but I don't see what Weka could do differently.

Comment: Could you please advise on how to get ROC AUC through R Weka?